# Enable "via status" facebook sdk android

Tags: android, facebook

Playing around with Facebook SDK v4.x I notice there is no "via app_display_name" text when using built in ShareLinkContent and ShareDialog

```
    ShareLinkContent content = new ShareLinkContent.Builder()
            .setContentUrl(Uri.parse(link))
            .build();
    dialog.show(content);
```

What i expect is: When share a link, It should have a "via text" right after the publish date time. (25/11/2015 via SDk sample).

Looking at the document: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/android

I see when using SharePhotoContent, the "via xxx" text is there but not ShareLinkContent.

Is it posible to enable this via text for ShareLinkContent using built in share dialog?

Thanks.

Comment: I just tested this on my own test app (the way you described) and I did get the "via App-Name" attribution. Is this still happening for you?

Comment: Thanks, I just configed to use the original facebook app after turn it on to public (not the test version) and the via text is there. :)